# React & Redux: Dispatching action not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a scenario where I am dispatching an action after an api call is successful.

```
axios.get(url)
       .then(response => {
         console.log("RESPONDED", response, dispatch)
         const payload = response
         dispatch(fetchSucess(payload))
       })
```

The snippet for `fetchSucess`:

```
const fetchSucess = (payload) => (dispatch) => {
  console.log("FETCH SUCCESS HAPPENED", payload)
  return {
    type: someActionTypes.FETCH_ALL_SUCCESS,
    payload,
  }
}
```

Now strangely FETCH_ALL_SUCCESS is not fired. if i replace the `return` with `dispatch` then it works. Why it is not working when I am dispatching it from the api callback?
Help would really appreciated!

Comment: are you using any middleware? thunk or saga?

Comment: @VishalSharma I am using thunk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this issue because `fetchSuccess` function is defined wrongly. If you will take a closer look you will notice that calling `fetchSucess(payload)` returns an **arrow function**:

```
(dispatch) => {
  console.log("FETCH SUCCESS HAPPENED", payload)
  return {
    type: someActionTypes.FETCH_ALL_SUCCESS,
    payload,
  }
}
```

while `dispatch` accepts an object so `fetchSuccess` function has to return an **action object**:

```
{
    type: someActionTypes.FETCH_ALL_SUCCESS,
    payload,
}
```

that is why `fetchSuccess` function should look similar to this:

```
const fetchSucess = (payload) => {
  console.log("FETCH SUCCESS HAPPENED", payload)
  return {
    type: someActionTypes.FETCH_ALL_SUCCESS,
    payload,
  }
}
```

Comment: actually, that's a correct definition for thunk. I think OP forgot to mention that.

Comment: ah yes, you are right. It was so obvious and I failed to see that. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the snippet, I'm assuming that you are using redux-thunk middleware (you forgot to mention that maybe?). In that case, the below approach is the right way. 
Here, `fetchData` is a thunk and `fetchSuccess` is an action.

```
const fetchSuccess = (payload) => ({
  type: someActionTypes.FETCH_ALL_SUCCESS,
  payload
})

const fetchData = () => (dispatch) => {
  axios.get(url)
     .then(response => {
       console.log("RESPONDED", response, dispatch)
       dispatch(fetchSuccess(response))
     })
}
```

Comment: Can't see any difference between with the answer below. redux-thunk does not make any difference here

Comment: um, yeah, you're right. I think I failed to understand your answer. kudos! :)